# error while creating buyer user using me register service

Tags: angular, api, ordercloud

i am trying to use the me-register end point but i am getting this error response
**

```
{
    "Errors": [
        {
            "ErrorCode": "User.IsNotTemp",
            "Message": "The current user is not a temp user. If you are trying to allow anonymous access to your app, see our guide on Anonymous Shopping.",
            "Data": null
        }
    ]
}
```

**

i have also added the Default Context User and enabled the Anonymous Buyer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PUT v1/register` endpoint is designed to allow users that have been shopping anonymously to profile themselves and transfer any order they may have created to the new user being registered.

That being said, when making the call you must be authenticated as the anonymous user, and then pass that anonymous user token into the URI. You can check the token by decoding it on [jtw.io](https://jwt.io). If there is an `orderid` in the token, it's an anonymous user token.